# Javascript / jQuery image rotator such as

Tags: javascript, jquery, rotator

I have a rough sketch of a image rotator / gallery I need but can't seem to find. If anyone knows any free plugins like this please reply.

[image: example]

Comment: Good grief a Google search for "jquery image carousel" or "jquery image rotator" returns a zillion results.  Which ones have you looked at and what exactly do you need that's different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be something you can use as a reference. You will probably need to modify the design a bit, but it can at least lead you in the right direction:

http://www.jcoverflip.com/demo

Always finding examples that fit your requirements can be difficult. I've always had to search for something similar and then go modify it myself, or learn how it works and write it from scratch.

Hope this helps.